# It's almost done, but the line is not continuous and is update

Tags: pine-script

Last time I asked a question about drawing a horizontal line,
there was no answer for few days so I learned over a few days
and succeeded in writing roughly using the For To syntax.

However, unlike the desired result, when the For statement is passed,
the existing line is lost and a new line is created.

What I want to do is check the starting bar of the exchange everyday
and draw a horizontal line with a high value for a beacon and a low value
for a negative one.

[What I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2vs1.png)

I want to get out of this yoke.

```
//@version=4
study(title = "Horizen Line", shorttitle = "Come on...", overlay = true)

t = timestamp("GMT", year(timenow), month(timenow), dayofmonth(timenow), 00, 00, 00)

var float l = 0.0
var bool c_color = true

for i = 1 to 2
    if time >= t and na(l[1])
        if close > open
            l := high, c_color := true
        else
            l := low, c_color := false
    else
        l := l[1]
    line.new(t, l, time, l, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend = extend.right, color = color.new(c_color ? color.teal : color.maroon, 80), style = line.style_solid, width = 1)
    t := t - 86400000 * i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you're looking for, but simplified.

```
//@version=4
study(title = "Horizen Line", shorttitle = "Come on...", overlay = true)

var color   c1 = color.new(color.teal,   0)
var color   c2 = color.new(color.maroon, 0)

if change(dayofmonth)
    l = close > open ? high : low
    line.new(time, l, time+1, l, xloc = xloc.bar_time, extend = extend.right, color = l == high ? c1 : c2, style = line.style_solid, width = 1)
```

This yields

[image: Example]

Comment: Thank you Sir, it really helped  me!